# Spring does not using sources in default locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've changed default locale in spring configuration, but spring always uses messages_en.properties instead of messages.properties.It seems that Spring is ignoring my choice of locale.

**defined locases:**

```
messages.properties
messages_en.properties
```

**Spring configuration:** 
*application-context.xml*

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="cs"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basenames">
    <list>
      <value>messages</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> 
</bean>
```

*servlet-context.xml*

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <mvc:interceptor>
  <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
  <exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
  <exclude-mapping path="/image/**"/>
  <exclude-mapping path="/ajax/**"/>
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
 </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**In JSP page**

```
<spring:message code="csn.terminology.csnId" />
<p>Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale}</p> 
<!-- output is 'cs', but messages are from messages_en.properties file -->
```

In project is used Spring Framework 3.2.4
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the bundles?

Comment: @Peter Jurkovič How did you solve this issue? Am having the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770383/localization-not-working-in-spring-4

Answer (score 4):

if it's the complete configuration then you forgot to add the locale resolver
You can add a SessionLocaleResolver like this and set the default locale property

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: then there is just one explanation for this ResourceBundleMessageSource has a property named  **setFallbackToSystemLocale** [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) which is default to true so if your locale file for locale cs doesn't contains message for a code then Your system locale is used.

Answer (score 0):

When locale is null, [AbstractMessageSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.java#L202) calls Locale.getDefault()

So you should set set default locale as follow:

```
   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      messageSource.setBasename("messages");
      // SET DEFAULT LOCALE AS WELL
      Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
      return messageSource;
   }
```

Comment: Hi Elie, this is probably not the desired solution, as you would set the JVMs default locale with `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale))
This might have a lot of unwanted consequences in a larger application