# Spring 4 messages_xx.properties are not picked as per Locale

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My application used to be on Spring 3.x Now we are on 4.x

my message property files are `messages_en.properties` and `messages_zh_TW.properties`
below is my messageSource config in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="core-messageSource"
    class="com.dc.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="com.dc.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="parentMessageSource">
        <ref bean="core-messageSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>application-messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="com.dc.core.common.UserSessionLocaleResolver"/>
```

Below is my `CustomResourceBundleMessageSource` class

```
public class CustomResourceBundleMessageSource extends ResourceBundleMessageSource {

    private final LoadingCache<Locale, LoadingCache<String, Optional<MessageFormat>>> messageFormatCache;
    {
        messageFormatCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
                new CacheLoader<Locale, LoadingCache<String, Optional<MessageFormat>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public LoadingCache<String, Optional<MessageFormat>> load(final Locale locale) throws Exception {
                        return CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<MessageFormat>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Optional<MessageFormat> load(String code) throws Exception {
                                return Optional.fromNullable(CustomResourceBundleMessageSource.super.resolveCode(code,
                                        locale));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    private final LoadingCache<Locale, LoadingCache<String, Optional<String>>>        messageCache;
    {
        messageCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
                new CacheLoader<Locale, LoadingCache<String, Optional<String>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public LoadingCache<String, Optional<String>> load(final Locale locale) throws Exception {
                        return CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Optional<String> load(String code) throws Exception {
                                return Optional.fromNullable(CustomResourceBundleMessageSource.super
                                        .resolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, locale));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        return messageFormatCache.getUnchecked(locale).getUnchecked(code).orNull();
    }

    protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {
        return messageCache.getUnchecked(locale).getUnchecked(code).orNull();
    }
}
```

below is my `UserSessionLocaleResolver` class

```
@Component
public class UserSessionLocaleResolver extends SessionLocaleResolver {

@Autowired
private IUserProfileService      userProfileService;

@Autowired
private ApplicationConfiguration appConfiguration;

@Override
public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object locale = request.getSession().getAttribute("UserLocale");
    String localeCode = (String) locale;
    if (localeCode != null) {
        if (localeCode.contains("-")) {
            String lCode[] = localeCode.split("-");
            return new Locale(lCode[0], lCode[1]);
        }
        else {
            return new Locale(localeCode);
        }
    }
    locale = getUserPreference();
    if (locale != null && !"".equals(locale)) {
        if (((String) locale).contains("-")) {
            String lCode[] = ((String) locale).split("-");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("UserLocale", locale);
            return new Locale(lCode[0], lCode[1]);
        }
        else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("UserLocale", locale);
            return new Locale((String) locale);
        }
    }

    return super.resolveLocale(request);
}

public Locale resolveLocaleOutsideRequest() {
    String locale = getUserPreference();
    if (locale != null && !"".equals(locale)) {
        if (locale.contains("-")) {
            String lCode[] = locale.split("-");
            return new Locale(lCode[0], lCode[1]);
        }
        else {
            return new Locale(locale);
        }
    }
    return new Locale(appConfiguration.getDefaultLocale());
}

private String getUserPreference() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        return preferences.getPreferredLocale();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

below is my collaportal-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="customJspViewResolver"
    class="com.dc.core.presentation.resolver.CustomJspViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/core/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="0" />

<bean id="viewNameTranslator" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator">
  <property name="stripExtension" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!--
    - Message source for this context, loaded from localized "messages_xx"
    files. - Could also reside in the root application context, as it is
    generic, - but is currently just used within Toolkit web tier.
-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.dc.core.spring.CustomDateEditorRegistrar"/>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

below is my web.xml

```
<display-name>CollaPortal</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.dc.core.spring.CustomXmlWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
    </param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.dc.core.security.listener.SessionListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CollabPortal</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>collaportal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xls</url-pattern>        
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have messages files for different locales as below in src\main\resources

`messages_en.properties` file

```
## format used for UI display of dates. see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
application.displayedDateFormat=M/d/yy
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateFormat=M/d/yy
## format used for UI display of date + time.
application.displayedDateTimeFormat=M/d/yy h:mm a
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateTimeFormat=M/d/yy h:mm a
```

`messages_zh_TW.properties` file

```
## format used for UI display of dates. see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
application.displayedDateFormat=yyyy/M/d
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateFormat=yyyy/M/d
## format used for UI display of date + time.
application.displayedDateTimeFormat=yyyy/M/d a h:mm
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateTimeFormat=yyyy/M/d a h:mm
```

I use the date format from property file in JSP as below to manipulate date display as per locale

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Date.format='<spring:message code="application.displayedDateFormat" />'.toLowerCase().replace(/yy/g, 'y');
//Date.Format is used here to manipulated dates as per the locale..........
</script>
```

I have a user preferences page in which user selects different locale and when a user selects the China-Taiwan locale spring supposed to pick up `messages_zh_TW.properties` file and `application.displayedDateFormat` should be yyyy/M/D in the JSP but its not. For whatever the locale user selects `application.displayedDateFormat` coming as M/d/yy

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to add `<property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />`  to your `core-messageSource` bean.

Comment: I just tried <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" /> with core-messageSource that didnt work either

Comment: Did you try debug your app? Add `${pageContext.response.locale}` to your JSP page and will see, witch locale is really used.

Comment: When I add the `${pageContext.response.locale}` am seeing the correct locale `zh_TW` but the `application.displayedDateFormat` coming as M/d/yy(date format for en locale) instead of yyyy/M/D(date format for zh_TW locale)