# Spring default locale not working as I expected for CookieLocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have two files for the text I want to translate:

messages_es_ES.properties
messages_en_US.properties

I'm using a CookieLocaleResolver:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("language");
    cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es_ES"));
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}
```

And this LocaleChangeInterceptor:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {        
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

In my jsp, I use this links:

```
<a href="?language=en_US">EN</a> 
<a href="?language=es_ES">ES</a>
```

Everything works, and the language is correctly changed when I click on one link, but everything is shown in English (in the system locale, to be more specific) when I start the application, even if I set "es_ES" as the default locale.

Comment: Do any of these answers help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573886/spring-mvc-the-default-locale-and-locale-change-doesnt-work

Comment: I'm afraid they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, I changed the property setFallbackToSystemLocale from the ResourceBundleMessageSource to false, as mentioned by @noobandy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945978/spring-does-not-using-sources-in-default-locale).
Now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default locale as follow:

```
   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      messageSource.setBasename("messages");
      // SET DEFAULT LOCALE AS WELL
      Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
      return messageSource;
   }
```

When locale is null, [AbstractMessageSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.java#L202) calls Locale.getDefault()